# Why the cannon is never rotating facing at the target?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I want is to make some ai that the cannon/turret will rotate automatic facing the target.
But when I'm running the game and moving the target in the scene view window the cannon is facing the other direction and not to the target.

The script to rotate:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateTurret : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float turnRateRadians = 2 * Mathf.PI;

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform turretTop; // the gun part that rotates

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform bulletSpawnPoint;

    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject target;

    void Update()
    {

        TargetEnemy();
    }

    void TargetEnemy()
    {
        if (target != null)
        {
            Vector3 targetDir = target.transform.position - transform.position;
            // Rotating in 2D Plane...
            targetDir.y = 0.0f;
            targetDir = targetDir.normalized;

            Vector3 currentDir = turretTop.forward;

            currentDir = Vector3.RotateTowards(currentDir, targetDir, turnRateRadians * Time.deltaTime, 1.0f);

            Quaternion qDir = new Quaternion();
            qDir.SetLookRotation(currentDir, Vector3.up);
            turretTop.rotation = qDir;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a screenshot showing where the script is attached to and when I'm moving with them ouse in the scene view the target the cube backward and forward not yet around the cannon the cannon is always facing the other direction:

[image: Turret]

And this is when running the game right after the game is running the turret automatic facing the other way and when moving the target the cube  the turret will keep rotating facing the other direction:

[image: Turret]

Comment: Can you show a video of the behaviour?

Comment: couldn't it be? `Vector3 targetDir = target.transform.position - turretTop.position;`

Comment: @Doh09 Here is a link for a short video clip I recorded showing the behaviour: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhGgHx43W1U&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think turretTop.forward represents the positive z dirrection of your model's local coordinates, but your barrel is alligned to the x-axis of the model.  Maybe if you replaced:

<strike>Vector3 currentDir = turretTop.forward;</strike>

with:

```
Vector3 currentDir = turretTop.right;
```

Comment: This could be the issue. Either `turretTop.right` or `-turretTop.right`. One of them should work

Comment: Changing it to turretTop.right or to -turretTop.right make it spinning nonstop.

Comment: Did it fix the "facing the other direction issue"? Can you add any video that shows the current issue?

Comment: I tested it now with a simple sphere and a cube like the gun attached to the sphere as child of it and added the script to the sphere and in the script I changed it to one line only for testing in the Update: transform.LookAt(target.transform); it's working fine. Something is wrong with the turret model I guess. Same line code is not working with the other model. Not sure if I can fix it and how I guess I will have to contact the author or maybe there is a way to fix it on my own?

Comment: @DanielLip I was working on a weapon system where some weapons needed transform.forward, some needed transform.right and so on. Perhaps set it individually which direction it shoots depending on model.